# Why do i get an stackoverflow error when using jackson even though using @JsonIgnoreProperties

Tags: java, jackson, stack-overflow, mixins, self-reference

I am trying to serialize a DefaultMutableTreeNode oject with jackson into a json string. Therefore i need to use a mix-in abstract class that is kind of a proxy to the DefaultMutableTreeNode class. This is probably because of self-reference fields but i am not able to recognize them.

Mix-in class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class DefaultMutableTreeNodeMixIn {

    @JsonCreator
    public DefaultMutableTreeNodeMixIn(@JsonProperty Object userObject) {};

    @JsonCreator
    public DefaultMutableTreeNodeMixIn(@JsonProperty Object userObject, 
    @JsonProperty boolean allowsChildren) {};

    @JsonProperty("childCount")
    abstract int getChildCount();

    @JsonProperty("depth")
    abstract int getDepth();

    @JsonProperty("firstChild")
    abstract TreeNode getFirstChild();

    @JsonProperty("firstLeaf")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getFirstLeaf();

    @JsonProperty("lastChild")
    abstract TreeNode getLastChild();

    @JsonProperty("lastLeaf")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getLastLeaf();

    @JsonProperty("leafCount")
    abstract int getLeafCount();

    @JsonProperty("level")
    abstract int getLevel();

    @JsonProperty("nextLeaf")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getNextLeaf();

    @JsonProperty("nextNode")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getNextNode();

    @JsonProperty("nextSibling")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getNextSibling();

    @JsonProperty("parent")
    abstract TreeNode getParent();

    @JsonProperty("path")
    abstract TreeNode[] getPath();

    @JsonProperty("previousLeaf")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getPreviousLeaf();

    @JsonProperty("previousNode")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getPreviousNode();

    @JsonProperty("previousSibling")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getPreviousSibling();

    @JsonProperty("siblingCount")
    abstract int getSiblingCount();

    @JsonProperty("isLeaf")
    abstract boolean isLeaf();

    @JsonProperty("isRoot")
    abstract boolean isRoot();
}
```

ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(DefaultMutableTreeNode.class,DefaultMutableTreeNodeMixIn.class);
String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(serverFileTree);
System.out.println(json);
```

(serverFileTree is an object of type DefaultMutableTreeNode)

Error trace:

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serializeContents(ObjectArraySerializer.java:252)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serialize(ObjectArraySerializer.java:213)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ObjectArraySerializer.serialize(ObjectArraySerializer.java:22)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) [...]
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:737)
... 1011 more
```

Comment: could you please add the stack trace here?

Comment: added it to the problems summary now

Comment: Instead of writing a mix-in, I think it would be much easier
to write a `JsonSerializer` for `DefaultMutableTreeNode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class generate cycles when you start travers theirs getters methods. To break them, you need to use `JsonBackReference` annotation. Your `mixin` could look like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
abstract class DefaultMutableTreeNodeMixIn {

    @JsonCreator
    public DefaultMutableTreeNodeMixIn(@JsonProperty Object userObject) {
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public DefaultMutableTreeNodeMixIn(@JsonProperty Object userObject, @JsonProperty boolean allowsChildren) {
    }

    @JsonProperty("childCount")
    abstract int getChildCount();

    @JsonProperty("depth")
    abstract int getDepth();

    @JsonProperty("firstChild")
    @JsonBackReference
    abstract TreeNode getFirstChild();

    @JsonProperty("firstLeaf")
    @JsonBackReference
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getFirstLeaf();

    @JsonProperty("lastChild")
    @JsonBackReference
    abstract TreeNode getLastChild();

    @JsonProperty("lastLeaf")
    @JsonBackReference
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getLastLeaf();

    @JsonProperty("leafCount")
    abstract int getLeafCount();

    @JsonProperty("level")
    abstract int getLevel();

    @JsonProperty("nextLeaf")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getNextLeaf();

    @JsonProperty("nextNode")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getNextNode();

    @JsonProperty("nextSibling")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getNextSibling();

    @JsonProperty("parent")
    abstract TreeNode getParent();

    @JsonProperty("path")
    @JsonBackReference
    abstract TreeNode[] getPath();

    @JsonProperty("previousLeaf")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getPreviousLeaf();

    @JsonProperty("previousNode")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getPreviousNode();

    @JsonProperty("previousSibling")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getPreviousSibling();

    @JsonProperty("siblingCount")
    abstract int getSiblingCount();

    @JsonProperty("isLeaf")
    abstract boolean isLeaf();

    @JsonProperty("isRoot")
    abstract boolean isRoot();
}
```

But probably the best and most `OOP` way is to create new `POJO` which represents your tree ready for serialisation and without cycles.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation of Jackson: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html

> public @interface JsonProperty
>
> Marker annotation that can be used to define a non-static method as a
>   "setter" or "getter" for a logical property (depending on its
>   signature), or non-static object field to be used (serialized,
>   deserialized) as a logical property.

I do think that you've annoted methods that are not setter or getter of properties.

For example:

```
@JsonProperty("previousNode")
    abstract DefaultMutableTreeNode getPreviousNode();
```

This method doesn't seems to not get a property, it's computing a node instead. Try to remove all the annotations on the methods to see if it solve the issue.

Comment: "getPreviousNode():
Returns the node that precedes this node in a preorder traversal of this node's tree." (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html) I made sure that all methods return values while annoting them